# JAVA integer overflow intrigue

Tags: java, bytecode

The 1st for loop in the below code does not find the maximum correctly due to an overflow. However, the 2nd for loop does. I used [godbolt.com](https://godbolt.org/) to look at the byte codes for this program which showed that to determine which number is greater the 1st for loop uses an **isub** and the 2nd for loop uses an **if_icmple**. Makes sense. However, why is the **if_icmple** able to successfully do this comparison since it too at some point must do a subtraction (which I would expect to produce an overflow)?

```
public class Overflow {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] nums = {3,-2147483648, 5, 7, 27, 9};
       
      int curMax = nums[0];
      for (int num : nums) {
         int diff = curMax - num; 
         if (diff < 0) {
            curMax = num;
         }
      }
      System.out.println("1) max is " + curMax);
       
      curMax = nums[0];
      for (int num : nums) {
         if (num > curMax) {
            curMax = num;
         }
      }  
      System.out.println("2) max is " + curMax);        
   }   
}
```

The output is

1. max is -2147483648
2. max is 27

Comment: Why should the second produce an overflow, too? That large negative number is a perfectly normal `int` that can be compared, the problem is only when you do `curMax - num`, i.e. `3 - -2147483648`, i.e. `3 + 2147483648`, which overflows and becomes negative.

Comment: I don't know Java's virtual machine but surely the comparison is discarding the result and only looking for the sign of the difference.

Comment: Why do you think it "must at some point do a subtraction"?

Comment: Besides the _sign bit_, there indeed also exists an _overflow flag_ flag. (like in neg - pos == pos)..

Comment: JAVA limits integers to 32 bits. I am assuming this is so the JVM can run a 32-bit processor. So I would think to compare the two numbers the processor at some point has to subtract them to see which is larger.

Comment: That doesn't have to be all the CPU does.  There are plenty of manual ways to check for overflow even if the CPU doesn't have an overflow flag.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say that comparison is implemented using subtraction. Contrary to various other opinions here, I'd say that is highly likely. Eg `cmp` on x86 is just a subtraction that does not update its destination register, only the flags. Various other (but maybe not *all*) processors that have a flags register also work that way. In the rest of this answer I'll use x86 as a representative processor for examples.

However, there is an incorrect assumption made implicitly by your code: a comparison is *not* equivalent to a subtraction followed by checking the sign, it is equivalent to a subtraction followed by checking some *combination* of the Zero, Sign, and Overflow flags. For example, if you implement `if (num > curMax)` using some `cmp` followed by `jle` (to skip the body of the `if` when the condition is false), then `jle` does this:

> Jump short if less or equal (ZF=1 or SF≠ OF).

Expressing the condition `SF≠ OF` directly in Java is not so easy. But the JVM itself has no such problem, it can use a comparison (or, equivalently, subtraction) followed by exactly the right kind of conditional jump.

There are some less-fortunate processors that do not have such as full set of conditional jumps as x86 has, but even in that case, the JVM has a lot more options than you do.

The option that the JVM does *not* have though, is implementing comparison incorrectly.

Comment: Even in the unlikely case that the CPU has no suitable set of conditions, it must have an idiomatic way of performing such a comparison, which the JVM can use. But the question is obviously targeting a CPU which has it.

Answer (score 0):

> However, why is the if_icmple able to successfully do this comparison since it too at some point must do a subtraction (which I would expect to produce an overflow)?

It doesn't need to do a subtraction.  It just needs to do a comparison.  Comparisons don't have to involve subtraction, certainly not in the CPU.

Of course, we can also take alternate steps to deal with overflow.  Here is one simple approach:

```
int cmp(int a, int b) {
  boolean aNeg = (a >>> 31) != 0;
  boolean bNeg = (b >>> 31) != 0;
  if (aNeg != bNeg) {
    return aNeg ? -1 : 1;
  }
  int diff = a - b; // subtracting two numbers with the same sign can't overflow
  return (diff == 0) ? 0 : (diff < 0) ? -1 : 1; 
}
```

All Java has to do is compile `if_icmple` to something like this, or whatever other instruction is appropriate on the target CPU.  Using bytecode means Java can leave that up to the runtime to get right for the target CPU, whatever's fastest in such an environment -- using the overflow bit, doing something like this, whatever.

Comment: How would a CPU (specifically a 32-bit CPU) do this comparison without doing a subtract?  Even a CPU compare instruction does a subtract (it just doesn't store the result).

Comment: Any number of ways.  If nothing else, you can flip the top bits to reduce it to an unsigned comparison, and then directly loop through the bits.